# Replace a text file which may or may not contain a space in file name

Tags: vbscript, filenames, space

I want to replace a file named with different name using VBScript. The input file name may or may not contain blank spaces.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' First parameter: original location\file
' Second parameter: new location\file
objFSO.CopyFile "D:\Development\abc  def.txt", "D:\Development\xyz.txt"
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Issue with MoveFile method to overwrite file in Destination in vbscript?](//stackoverflow.com/a/17065729)

Comment: Possibly related: [Copy a file from one folder to another using vbscripting](//stackoverflow.com/q/1260740)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, `CopyFile` creates a copy of the source file. To rename a file you could use [`MoveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6.aspx), but the usual approach is to simply change the [name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zawxett8.aspx) of the file:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject")
fso.GetFile("D:\Development\abc  def.txt").Name = "xyz.txt"
```

---

**Edit:** If you actually mean to replace one file with another file, you can do so with [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w.aspx) by setting the third parameter (*overwrite*) to `True`, as [@Lankymart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927250/replace-a-text-file-which-may-or-may-not-contain-a-space-in-file-name/42927513?noredirect=1#comment72955168_42927513) pointed out in the comments.

```
fso.CopyFile "D:\Development\abc  def.txt", "D:\Development\xyz.txt", True
```

If you don't want to keep the source file you need to delete it after the copy operation (VBScript doesn't allow moving a file over an existing file). Alternatively you can delete the destination file first and then move or rename the source file.

Comment: Do they want to keep the original though and overwrite still if the destination file exists? if so just specifying `objFSO.CopyFile "D:\Development\abc  def.txt", "D:\Development\xyz.txt", True` would be enough. The fact the question says *"Replace"* would suggest not, but I wouldn't assume either.